# problem while uploading apk on play store

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-manifest

When I upload my apk on the playStore(release in alpha), I am getting this error:

> Upload failed
>   You need to use a different package name because
>   [name of package] is used by a pre-installed
>   application. To upload a pre-installed application, please contact
>   Google Play Developer Support. Learn more.

However, it is my first release and no one is using this package name. 
Last thing, the version code is 1531. Maybe is it due to that? FOr the first release, I have to set it to 1?

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: What is the package name of your app which you made?

Comment: This is more of google play support question. Consider changing package name or contact google play developer support  as instructed.

Comment: I cannot give the package name since it is one from my company and I cannot change the package name because it is for my company and they want this one.
But when I go to this link : https://market.android.com/details
I see that the package name does not exist. And I just have the apk, not the code. I see there that the version is 1531. DO you see it could be link to this??

Comment: @Bazouk55555 Were you able to solve it ? facing same error.

Comment: @shashankmishra...no unfortunately...i still dont know what happened (I actually left that subject to someone else and I know they tried to reach google support)

Answer (score 2):

There exists other application with the same package name for sure.

You can refactor-rename your package name, and make it sure that changes reflect in a manifest file, Proguard configuration etc.

Comment: I cannot give the package name since it is one from my company and I cannot change the package name because it is for my company and they want this one.
But when I go to this link : https://market.android.com/details
I see that the package name does not exist. And I just have the apk, not the code. I see there that the version is 1531. DO you see it could be link to this??

Answer (score 0):

Copy your Package name in the Manifest file 
         `<package="com.example.myapplication">` Press **ctrl+shift+R** enter your old package name and replace with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Your application is having the same named package, which is already used by some other app on play store.

The solution is to change the package name using refactoring. It will change your package name.

Comment: I cannot give the package name since it is one from my company and I cannot change the package name because it is for my company and they want this one.
But when I go to this link : https://market.android.com/details
I see that the package name does not exist. And I just have the apk, not the code. I see there that the version is 1531. DO you see it could be link to this??